# How to adjust the SQL or machine memory to accommodate for spikes and machine freezes due to high `granted workspace memory`?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Edition: SQL 2019 enterprise

Machine memory: 130GB

SQL Server max memory: 110.5GB

SQL server and machine has steady usage of 110.5GB and 112GB respectively.

Occasionally there are spikes where SQL server utilizes 119.5GB (about 9GB more than sql max memory config) which causes memory pressure on the machine and machine freezes for a while. Perf mon counters indicate spike in machine memory, sql memory and `granted workspace memory` during this time.

Granted workspace memory is used for sort/hash/index operations.

Does the granted workspace memory fit within the sql max memory setting?

Has this any relation with lock pages in memory being enabled which is why maybe sql isn't releasing its own memory (buffer memory, etc) for its own sort/hash/index operation work (granted workspace memory)?

Comment: Why does allocating 199GB cause "memory pressure" on the machine.  It's got 130GB of RAM and at least a 138GB commit limit.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this well written [DBA.StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188181/150011) on what things the `Max Server Memory` setting limits and doesn't limit.

Briefly, it controls:

> max server memory controls the SQL Server memory allocation, including the buffer pool, compile memory, all caches, qe memory grants, lock manager memory, and clr memory (essentially any memory clerk found in sys.dm_os_memory_clerks).

It does not control:

> Memory for thread stacks, memory heaps, linked server providers other than SQL Server, and any memory allocated by a non SQL Server DLL are not controlled by max server memory.

---

> Does the amount of machine and sql memory need increasing? Or can sql memory be reduced to say 100GB, thus leaving 30GB free rather than current 110.5GB which leaves 20.5GB free?

This just depends on the workload of your SQL Server, so we really can't say without in depth profiling of it over time. But generally speaking, I believe the OS and SQL Server itself have processes to detect Memory pressure and release some of the consumed Memory when needed. Despite that, if your instance is causing enough Memory pressure on the machine for the whole machine to freeze then I'd say it sounds likely your instance's workload actually needs the Memory it's using, and you'll probably be better off increasing the amount of Memory available on the machine itself.

Comment: So increase machine memory and leave the sql max memory as it is? Does lock pages in memory have any relation to this situation?

Comment: @variable Yea likely you want to increase the Memory provisioned to the machine, but leave the `Max Server Memory` as is. The Memory spike you're seeing on the machine is going to be due to something outside of what `Max Server Memory` relates to anyway. It sounds like your machine is what's choking.

Comment: @variable I would assume the lock pages in Memory feature allocates to the Buffer Pool cache which **is** limited by the `Max Server Memory` setting, so that wouldn't relate to spike you're seeing on the machine. But I honestly don't know for certain. If you're using CLR on your server, I could see that being the culprit possibly.

Comment: CLR is disabled. Is granted workspace memory (sorting/hashing) outside of the sql max memory?